# Dictionary of a class

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<SymbolAndStrategy, int> allPositions
```

SymbolAndStrategy is a class containing 2 different class, Class Symbol and Class Strategy. But when I tried to use it like as this,

```
allPositions.Add(new SymbolAndStrategy(StrategyName.Apple, this.ProductKey), 0);
allPositions[new SymbolAndStrategy(StrategyName.Apple, this.ProductKey)]++;
```

the compiler will complain "key not found" even the 2 have the SymbolAndStrategy key.

Comment: No they are not the same. In the Add you are creating a reference to a class SymbolAndStrategy, in the indexer you are creating a new reference to a different object of type SymbolAndStrategy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complain of the compailer is probabbly derives from the fact that you didn't override `GetHashCode()` and `Equal()` methods of your type in order to make equal 2 different instances by their  *content*.

In short

`new SymbolAndStrategy(StrategyName.Apple, this.ProductKey)` create a *new* instance, a *new* allocation. In order to "explain" to the framework that those 2 instances are equal (the one present in the dictionary as a key, and another you use for a query) you need to override those 2 methods mentioned above accordingly inside `SymbolAndStrategy` type.

More on that [Implementing the Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Dang... You got it before me heh

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behaviour because reference types are compared by reference. Even though your objects have the content they are not treated as equal because they have different references. If you don't want this you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method in your class.

Or you can implement an `IEqualityComparer` for your class and pass it to Dictionary constructor, so it will be used instead of the default comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the fact that, by default, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` will use `Object.Equals` to test for key equality. If you didn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class, then `Object.Equals` will use reference equality. Since you're creating two instances of your key (albeit with the same values), `Object.Equals` will return `false`.

There are two solutions.

1. Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class.
2. Use [the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` constructor that takes an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That will allow you to implement an equality check without having to modify the original class if you don't have the ability.